# WP Feed namespace attr issue

Tags: media, rss, feed

Having a strange issue (well, strange to me) where an xmlns:media namespace attr is being added to one feed but not the other.

How do I get rid of the "xmlns:media" attr?  I don't even know why it's being added to one feed but not the other.

For example: http://pridemoreproperties.agentfire.com/feed/

Notice the "xmlns:media" being added.

http://landandvillage.com/feed/

These are on the same WP install (WP Multisite) and both using the genesis theme.

Comment: Not sure if this comes from WordPress; I could not find such code. Have you searched in the theme files for that?

Comment: I did and the only place I can find ANY reference to this namespace is in the wp-includes/class-simplepie.php file in the SIMPLEPIE_NAMESPACE_MEDIARSS constant.